# Adding Properties on a complex object for JSON serialization

Tags: c#, javascript, json, serialization

I have a complex object that looks something like this, that I would like to serialize as JSON and pass to my client side(javascript):

```
public class MyObject
{
   [title("title1")]
   public int? MyInt{get;set;}

   [title("title2")]
   public string MyStr{get;set;}

   // ETC
}
```

Today's JSON serialization will be something like this:

```
{MyInt: '7', MyStr: 'Str'}
```

I would like my new JSON to look something like this:

```
{
  MyInt: {value:'7', title:'title1', <Extra info>}, 
  MyStr: {value:'Str', title:'title2', <Extra info>}
}
```

Is there a good way to do this?
This is going to happen a lot in my system so I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is by building a custom serializer that creates a new object for every property and looks for annotation to set as values.